# android studio не видит java 1.8

Tags: java, android, linux

Linux
при запущенном as появляется сообщение:
ошибка при рендеринге:
для android marsrallow требуется java 1.8 или выше

но когда я в консоли пишу java -version, то выводит java 1.8.0. что тут не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Если вы это видите в графическом редакторе разметки - то не расстраивайтесь. У вас всё нормально, это просто предпросмоторщик не работает. Починить его нельзя, да и не нужно.Просто не пользуйтесь им.

Comment: http://vk.com/wall-129234927_24 у меня ничего нету, только надпись

Comment: Фото экрана?.. Серьёзно?.. Вы про скриншоты слышали?.. И таки подробнее о проблеме расскажите - у вас AS вообще не работает или только редактор разметки?

Comment: дело было ночью, надо было спать. поэтому итолько камера

Answer (score 2):

В меню студии:

```
File-> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location -> вводим путь к JDK 8
```

Comment: ошибка всё равно осталась, но я указал правильный путь к jre... TeamViewer есть?

Comment: @veselcraft, извините, некогда. Попробуйте теперь перезапустить студию.

Comment: я её и так перезапускал, тажа ошибка